# Using Eigen::BICGSTAB with OpenMP with incomplete ILU is not running in parallel

Tags: openmp, eigen, solver

I have BICGSTAB not running in parallel with incomplete LU preconditionner:
I use g++ under DEBIAN with the compile option -fopenmp
Please help me.
My call to Eigen solve is:

```
initParallel();
omp_set_num_threads(8);
setNbThreads(8);

// Fill Eigen Row Major sparse matrix            
SparseMatrix<double,RowMajor> A(n,n);
A.setFromTriplets(T.begin(), T.end());

//map std::vector B to Eigen VectorXd
Map<Eigen::VectorXd> b(B_.data(), B_.size());


// BICGSTAB
BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double,RowMajor>, Eigen::IncompleteLUT<double>  >  solver(A);
solver.setTolerance(1e-15);

VectorXd X(n);
X = solver.solve(b);
```

Comment: That's strange. The code looks OK to me. Moreover, you say that the `-fopenmp` compiler flag is set. Maybe you could try to add `solver.compute()` before calculating `X`. Also, I would suggest adding `A.makeCompressed()` after the matrix has been set up. But that should not have an effect on parallelization.

Comment: I tried adding both but it is sill sequential. Thanks